# Jquery UI - Setting a default Tab which use Content via Ajax

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using AJAX Tabs with the Jquery UI library. I need to change the default tab based on the page. I did a lot of searching and tried a lot. Unfortunately i have not seen any example being implemented on the Ajax Tabs.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Test</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="uistyle.css" />
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#tabs" ).tabs()({
active: 2,
beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
ui.jqXHR.error(function() {
ui.panel.html(
"Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " +
"If this wouldn't be a demo." );
});
}
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Tab 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Tab 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Tab3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is use hash tags.  So you say if your page is index.html.  You could say:

javascript:

```
if (window.location.hash == '#page1') $( "#tabs" ).tabs({ active: 1 });
```

html

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html#page1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html#page2">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html#page3">Tab3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```